# Can you check if a message is a response to a wait_for coroutine in pycord

Tags: discord, discord.py, pycord

My bot is meant to mimic social media posts within a server. It sends a certain webhook embed post every time there's a message in a particular channel  (`on_message`).

The webhook embed post has buttons such as "share". When a user clicks that button, the bot awaits their next message in the channel to send a different type of embed post. However, because the bot is already posting off of every message event, both functions go off, sending both posts. Is there a way for the bot to detect or check for if the message sent after hitting "share" is fulfilling the "share" function's `wait_for` coroutine, so it knows not to double-post (i.e. not have the first event go off)? Or some other way?

I know that the easiest way to do this would be to have it as a command of some sort, but I want there to be limited chances for a user to mess up when it comes to "post"ing so that no messages in those channels are default (normal) messages, only the "platform" messages.

A snippet of my code is here: https://pastebin.com/Z8VNUHQQ

Relevant lines:

39- `comment = await bot.wait_for(event='message', check=check)`

90- `async def on_message(message)`

Comment: well no, not really.

Comment: can you elaborate? is there any other option I can take?

Comment: There's nothing to elaborate, you simply cannot do it. Even if you modify the source code it'd be really difficult to make it work.